# PubSub Dead Lettering

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, dead-letter

I'm trying to forward a cloud function pubsub subscription to a dead letter topic as described here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/dead-letter-topics#gcloud

I tried

```
$ gcloud pubsub subscriptions update gcf-worker-topic --dead-letter-topic=gcf-worker-dead-letter-topic
```

and also tried modifying the gcf-worker-topic subscription in the Console. Both gave me the same error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.pubsub.subscriptions.update) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The supplied AppEngine URL project does not match the subscription's parent project
```

The goal is to forward messages to a dead letter queue when the cloud function crashes.

What am I doing wrong?  Is this not supported?  Are there plans for future support?

Answer (score 3):

When you plug directly your Cloud Function to a topic, an automatic push subscription is created with a strange endpoint:

```
https://d4d1290519676f29baf13a7bf18a25bf-dot-jea3ef1cff72566d8-tp.appspot.com/_ah/push-handlers/pubsub/projects/PROJECT_ID/topics/test-topic?pubsub_trigger=true
```

You can see that this URL is in `appspot.com`, which is typical of App Engine. So, the Cloud Function directly plugged to PubSub generate a strange Hack that use AppEngine in an external/google project. You can't update it.

The work around is to change your Cloud Function in HTTP triggered mode and to create a PubSub push subscription on it. However, be careful because the PubSub message format aren't exactly the same

- With push subscription:

```
   {
     "message": {
       "attributes": {
         "key": "value"
       },
       "data": "SGVsbG8gQ2xvdWQgUHViL1N1YiEgSGVyZSBpcyBteSBtZXNzYWdlIQ==",
       "messageId": "136969346945"
     },
     "subscription": "projects/myproject/subscriptions/mysubscription"
   }
```

- With direct link to Cloud Function: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#event_structure

Answer (score 0):

You might also need `--dead-letter-topic-project`. See the [dosumentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/subscriptions/update).

Comment: Thanks, I tried and got the same error.  Another thread says that cloud function pusbsub subscriptions are created by a Google managed project thus the names don't match.  I want to believe that it's still possible to do this somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are updating the `topic id` (gcf-worker-topic) instead of the `subscription id`.

It's in the subscription that the `dead-letter-topic` is defined. Try to create an new subscription:

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions create subscription-id \
  --topic=gcf-worker-topic \
  --dead-letter-topic=gcf-worker-dead-letter-topic \
  --max-delivery-attempts=max-delivery-attempts \
  [--dead-letter-topic-project=dead-letter-topic-project]
```